# sqlite database not returning results

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

Why my query does not return results?
I'm using C#.
It returns column headers but no rows. Is there a problem with my select statement?

here's my code :

```
conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=local.db;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;");
DataTable data = new DataTable();
SQLiteDataReader reader;
using (SQLiteTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction())
{
    using (SQLiteCommand mycommand = new SQLiteCommand(conn))
    {
        mycommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TAGTABLE WHERE TAG = '"+tag+"' ;";
        reader = mycommand.ExecuteReader();
    }
    trans.Commit();
    data.Load(reader);
    reader.Close();
    reader.Dispose();
    trans.Dispose();
}
return data;
```

The `TAGTABLE` has following fields:

```
TID int,
Tag varchar(500),
FilePath varchar(1000)
```

Comment: Did you try to execute exactly same questy into SQLite designer of VS. ?

Comment: yes it worked,but in my program its not returning rows.

Comment: Did you debug the application? what is happening?

Comment: @armin I suspect the transaction is doing something funky to the entire command, I've posted some amended code that should work as expected.  I can't answer what the `trans.Commit` line would do, I've no idea.

Comment: @armin There might be something funny with the column names, can you list the column names being returned and also some sample data?  Also, can you provide a sample value of what `tag` might contain.

Comment: @Tarun I debugged it and nothing unusual happens.

Comment: @Adam Houldsworth my column names are TID,Tag,FilePath.I manually added some test data like below
TID    TAG     FilePath
1       a       b
2       c       d
....
and tag is for example a.but it just returns column names,not any rows.I also remove transaction block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the transaction, try the following:

```
    DataTable data = new DataTable();

    using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=local.db;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;"))
    using (SQLiteCommand mycommand = new SQLiteCommand(conn))
    {
        mycommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TAGTABLE WHERE TAG = @tag;";
        mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tag", tag);
        conn.Open();

        using (SQLiteDataReader reader = mycommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
            data.Load(reader);  
        }
    }

    return data;
```

The most likely reason this won't return anything is if the `SELECT` doesn't yield any results.

Also note that anything implementing the `IDisposable` interface can be used in conjunction with the `using` statement, so manual closing / disposal of objects afterwards is not required.

Notice that the SQL has changed to use a parameterized query, this will help reduce the likelihood of SQL injection attacks, and is generally cleaner.

Comment: Still not working,only returning columns not rows.by the way I'm using system.data.sqlite wrapper.

Comment: @armin What are the column names of the columns being returned?

Comment: Columns : TID int,Tag varchar(500),FilePath varchar(1000)

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't show sample data and what should be returend some general pointers only:

- The way you build the SQL is wide open to SQL incjection (a serious security issue)
- Depending on the value of `tag` (for example if it contains `'`) the above SQL Statement would do something you don't expect
- Since everything is wrappend in `using` (a good thing!) the question is, whether there is some exception thrown inside the `using` block (check with the debugger)
- why are you using a transaction ? I can't see any reason which makes that necessary...

***Please show some sample data with param value and expected result...***

Comment: security and injection is not an issue for me here,it's local program for manipulating images.no ones gonna bother coming up with an attack.

Comment: select is working fine in sqlite manager,just not working in my program

Comment: no exception is thrown,I traced the program step by step,but still no clue.and somebody told me using transactions would be a good programing practice.

Comment: transactions are a good practice but not for everything... usually when you just SELECT there is seldomn need for a transaction... please show the valud of `tag` AND some sample data